# What is "product wrapper" XML name?

Tags: magento2, category, xml, frontend

I'm trying to move products element and can't find it's name to reference via XML.
The element has class "products wrapper grid products-grid" in rendered HTML.

Using Magento 2.

[image: This is the block]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

So the **block name** is : "`category.products.list`"

**Path**: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

**Example :** to remove that block you have to do this:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing this referenced in the following file: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

Comment: There is only html structure with classes. But do you know the XML name? How can I reference to this block/container?

Answer (score 0):

You can move product blog with move xml element

Path: Your-theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/atalog_category_view.xml

```
<move element="category.products" destination="name.of.destination.element" />
```